# Unable to install global modules using sudo npm

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, pm2

I was trying to install pm2, sails.js for Node.js from a non-root user with sudo. I get the below error:

```
sudo npm install pm2 -g
sudo: npm: command not found
```

but when i try to install using the below command, it works

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/npm install pm2 -g
```

How can i make sudo npm work?

Thanks.

How i installed Node and npm with su previously:

```
su - 
yum install gcc-c++ openssl-devel python
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf node-latest.tar.gz
(cd into extracted folder: ex "cd node-v0.10.3")
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Maybe `/usr/local/bin/` is not in your `PATH`. When you run `echo $PATH`, do you see `/usr/local/bin` in the result?

Comment: I reinstalled my server. But how do i install node.js and npm without sudo to avoid this issue in the future. I installed using the above procedure previously. (updated in question)

Comment: I always use [this method](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814#file-take-ownership-sh), it's from Isaac Schlueter, the creator of `npm`. In the same gist file there are other methods, if you want to try.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to that method. I choose the first one. :-)

Comment: When i try to execute the last command curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh --- i get an error: sh: line 1: Moved: command not found :-(

Comment: It works with curl -L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thanks to everyone who helped me out! Just like @Rodrigo Medeiros advised me, i installed node.js and npm using the below method taken from (https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814#file-take-ownership-sh) but modified two lines of commands as per the advise from a comment posted by deesejohn in that page.

```
cd
sudo yum install gcc-c++
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
make install # ok, fine, this step probably takes more than 30 seconds...
curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Check installed version using `node -v` and `npm -v`

Now, i am able to install npm modules globally without sudo permissions, there are many ways to install node.js and npm but this worked for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It means the npm is not install with sudo, so it is not in the path of root. I think, it is better to always use npm without 'sudo'. Because you can keep the packaged installed with npm in your local environment.

If you really want to use with sudo, you can re-install node with sudo.

Comment: I reinstalled my server. But how do i install node.js and npm without sudo to avoid this issue in the future. I installed using the above procedure previously. (updated in question)

Comment: I install node with the pre-built binary package directly (up-package, set path and use), in which the npm is already packaged. And it will be easy to use.

Comment: If possible do advise how to install directly from binary? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NPM is not installed on your system.
you can check first if node is set perfectly.

$node -v

it will give version.
if yes then check

$npm -v

if its not giving version may be your environment path is not set then execute

$PATH=/usr/bin/node:$PATH

and just check node -v and npm -v . if npm gives version number. thats it. It will install global package.